# Keyerror default_permission with HelpCommand

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

I was trying to run my bot with cogs and slash commands in it. I experienced the following error which made the custom help command not work at all.

### Error

```
loaded cogs.moderation
Ignoring exception in on_connect
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server513038/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 352, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server513038/Bot2/bot.py", line 21, in on_connect
    await bot.sync_commands()
  File "/home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server513038/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/bot.py", line 542, in sync_commands
    registered_commands = await self.register_commands(global_commands, force=force)
  File "/home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server513038/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/bot.py", line 420, in register_commands
    desynced = await self.get_desynced_commands(guild_id=guild_id)
  File "/home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server513038/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/bot.py", line 302, in get_desynced_commands
    if getattr(cmd, check) != match[check]:
KeyError: 'default_permission'
```

### Code:

**Bot.py**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
load_dotenv()

from classes.help import SupremeHelpCommand
bot = discord.Bot(command_prefix="-", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
    
async def on_ready():
    cogs_list = [
    'moderation',
    'owner',
    'fun'
    ]

    for cog in cogs_list:
        bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{cog}')
        print(f"loaded cogs.{cog}")
        await bot.sync_commands()
    await bot.sync_commands()
    print(f"{bot.user} is ready and online!")
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game(name="/helpme"))






bot.help_command = SupremeHelpCommand()

@bot.slash_command(name="test", description="test")
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.respond("Hi")

bot.add_application_command(test)





bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

**cogs/moderation.py**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Moderation(commands.Cog):
     def __init__(self, bot): # this is a special method that is called when the cog is loaded
        self.bot = bot

def setup(bot): # this is called by Pycord to setup the cog
    bot.add_cog(Moderation(bot)) # add the cog to the bot
```

**classes/help.py** (Where my SupremeHelpCommand is defined)

```py
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import HelpCommand, Cog, Command
from discord.ext import commands


class SupremeHelpCommand(commands.HelpCommand):
    def get_command_signature(self, command):
        return '%s%s %s' % (self.context.clean_prefix, command.qualified_name, command.signature)

    async def send_bot_help(self, mapping):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Help", color=discord.Color.blurple())
        for cog, commands in mapping.items():
            filtered = await self.filter_commands(commands, sort=True)
            if command_signatures := [
                self.get_command_signature(c) for c in filtered
            ]:
                cog_name = getattr(cog, "qualified_name", "No Category")
                embed.add_field(name=cog_name, value="\n".join(command_signatures), inline=False)

        channel = self.get_destination()
        await channel.send(embed=embed)

    async def send_command_help(self, command):
        embed = discord.Embed(title=self.get_command_signature(command) , color=discord.Color.blurple())
        if command.help:
            embed.description = command.help
        if alias := command.aliases:
            embed.add_field(name="Aliases", value=", ".join(alias), inline=False)

        channel = self.get_destination()
        await channel.send(embed=embed)

    async def send_help_embed(self, title, description, commands): # a helper function to add commands to an embed
        embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=description or "No help found...")

        if filtered_commands := await self.filter_commands(commands):
            for command in filtered_commands:
                embed.add_field(name=self.get_command_signature(command), value=command.help or "No help found...")

        await self.get_destination().send(embed=embed)

    async def send_group_help(self, group):
        title = self.get_command_signature(group)
        await self.send_help_embed(title, group.help, group.commands)

    async def send_cog_help(self, cog):
        title = cog.qualified_name or "No"
        await self.send_help_embed(f'{title} Category', cog.description, cog.get_commands())
```

I am really clueless about what to do since it doesn't give me any hints in the error as to what caused the error.

Comment: it’s literally a keyerror one of the simplest ones to debug, your match dict doesn’t have a key called “default_permission”

Comment: so in the commands, i simply have to add default_permission="Permission"?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński

Comment: yes exactly @Karo

Comment: Would editing the title to: "How do I instance multiple cogs" be more fitting? Tags in titles aren't good.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński The error is within the library itself and a function that he is calling. He's most likely using the library method improperly. In his code, he never indexed 'default permission'.